# Touche global gestures grayed out and says "used by GNOME"

Tags: x11, gnome, manjaro

I just installed Manjaro 21.3.1 (with gnome 42) on my laptop and 3 and 4 finger gestures don't work.

[image: Touché UI grayed out]

I tried reinstalling Touchegg from AUR as well as Touché (the UI app).
I also tried those command lines from the Touchegg [repository](https://github.com/JoseExposito/touchegg#readme) :

```
$ sudo systemctl enable touchegg.service
$ sudo systemctl start touchegg
```

And the service is active and running :

```
● touchegg.service - Touchégg Daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/touchegg.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sun 2022-07-03 12:42:52 CEST; 6min ago
       Docs: https://github.com/JoseExposito/touchegg/tree/master/installation#readme
   Main PID: 508 (touchegg)
      Tasks: 4 (limit: 9176)
     Memory: 13.8M
        CPU: 2.763s
     CGroup: /system.slice/touchegg.service
             └─508 /usr/bin/touchegg --daemon
```

I also verified if my track-pad could handle gestures.

```
Device:           MSFT0001:02 06CB:7F8F Touchpad
Kernel:           /dev/input/event7
Group:            6
Seat:             seat0, default
Size:             102x67mm
Capabilities:     pointer gesture
```

Finally, I tried to install [x11 gestures](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4033/x11-gestures/) from gnome extensions but still nothing.

Is there any way to solve this issue?
(I would prefer not using Wayland as it breaks some apps like Teams.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find a solution to "ungray" the settings.

I went to `/home/.config/touchegg.conf`
and replaced all the

```
<action type="GNOME_SHELL"></action>
```

by

```
<action type="SHOW_DESKTOP">
        <animate>true</animate>
</action>
```

And then I changed manually in the Touché GUI what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

I was using the Gesture Improvements gnome extension to configure 3 and 4 finger swipes. But after upgrading to Ubuntu 23.10 (gnome version 45), I was no longer able to use that.

I looked around and found X11 Gestures extension which requires Touchegg. I configured it as mentioned in the question, however found that it had all the options for 3 and 4 finger swipes 'grayed-out' and not able to use. I found the above answer by Sanicos useful. Thought of writing this answer and correct/build on that.

The file to be modified is at `/home/USERNAME/.config/touchegg/` or `~/.config/touchegg/`

You can directly open it in gedit (text editor) application. Type the below in the terminal:

```
gedit ~/.config/touchegg/touchegg.conf
```

Here, look for lines containing:

```
<action type="GNOME_SHELL"></action>
```

In my case I have set the `Number of Fingers for Swipe Action` to `4` in the X11 Gestures (extension settings). So, now I'm looking to change the swipe actions with 3 fingers in the Touchegg GUI `Touché`.

So these are the lines in the `touchegg.conf` file that I need to change:

```
<gesture type="SWIPE" fingers="3" direction="UP">
  <action type="GNOME_SHELL"></action>
</gesture>

<gesture type="SWIPE" fingers="3" direction="DOWN">
  <action type="GNOME_SHELL"></action>
</gesture>

<gesture type="SWIPE" fingers="3" direction="LEFT">
  <action type="GNOME_SHELL"></action>
</gesture>

<gesture type="SWIPE" fingers="3" direction="RIGHT">
  <action type="GNOME_SHELL"></action>
</gesture>
```

Ensure `type='SWIPE'`, `fingers="3"`, and directions in each one. All we need to do now is to configure the action.

```
<gesture type="SWIPE" fingers="3" direction="UP">
  <action type="MAXIMIZE_RESTORE_WINDOW"></action>
</gesture>

<gesture type="SWIPE" fingers="3" direction="DOWN">
  <action type="MAXIMIZE_RESTORE_WINDOW"></action>
</gesture>

<gesture type="SWIPE" fingers="3" direction="LEFT">
  <action type="SEND_KEYS">
    <modifiers>Alt_L</modifiers>
    <keys>Shift_L+Tab</keys>
    <repeat>true</repeat>
    <animation>NONE</animation>
    <decreaseKeys>Alt_L+Tab</decreaseKeys>
  </action>
</gesture>

<gesture type="SWIPE" fingers="3" direction="RIGHT">
  <action type="SEND_KEYS">
    <modifiers>Alt_L</modifiers>
    <keys>Tab</keys>
    <repeat>true</repeat>
    <animation>NONE</animation>
    <decreaseKeys>Alt_L+Shift_L+Tab</decreaseKeys>
  </action>
</gesture>
```

So here's what I've done:

- Swipe Up   → Maximise / Restore the Window
- Swipe Down → Maximise / Restore the Window
- Swipe Right → Switch to the Next Window (Using Alt+Tab key combinations continuously, and also enabled the reverse)
- Swipe Left → Switch to the Previous Window (Using Alt+Shift+Tab key combinations continuously, and also enabled the reverse)

This helps me quickly maximize and restore windows I work on with simple Up and DOWN 3 finger swipes. And 3 finger LEFT and RIGHT swipes let me seamlessly switch between windows in the workspace.

You can of course now head to the `Touché` GUI app and configure the SWIPES to your liking.